# Python XML parsing failure

Tags: python, xml, parsing, urllib2, eve

I have a simple function to retrieve an XML from a site, and store it in a string:

```
def market(typeid):
  ping = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?usesystem=30000142&typeid=' + str(typeid))
  info = ping.read()
  return info
```

I then use the ElementTree library to parse the XML, but this doesn't work, no errors exactly, but it seems it thinks the XML code is only a couple lines long and stops there, whereas there are many more elements. I am looking for elements far below the first few, and it stops after the first couple elements, thinking it has reached the end of the document or something? I can't quite figure it out after looking around on the net for quite a while, found nothing helpful. The XML as printed out in my shell is as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<evec_api version="2.0" method="marketstat_xml">
  <marketstat><type id="34">
      <buy><volume>14082197693</volume><avg>5.61</avg><max>5.89</max><min>4.61</min><stddev>0.46</stddev><median>5.57</median><percentile>5.87</percentile></buy>
      <sell><volume>19614612791</volume><avg>6.31</avg><max>10.00</max><min>5.90</min><stddev>0.64</stddev><median>6.15</median><percentile>6.00</percentile></sell>
      <all><volume>34096810484</volume><avg>5.95</avg><max>10.00</max><min>0.50</min><stddev>0.84</stddev><median>6.03</median><percentile>4.26</percentile></all>
    </type></marketstat>
</evec_api>
```

To start the parsing I am using

```
root = ET.fromstring(data)
```

and have imported ElementTree as ET. From what I read, it was the only way to 'inject' the XML as a string and not a file. I suppose if there was a simple way to download the file to a temp location, and use the file version, that would work aswell, but I am at a dead-end with this one.

Upon running `print ET.tostring(root)` I get:

```
<evec_api method="marketstat_xml" version="2.0">
  <marketstat><type id="34">
      <buy><volume>19627488095</volume><avg>5.69</avg><max>5.91</max>    <min>4.61</min><stddev>0.44</stddev><median>5.81</median><percentile>5.90</percentile></buy>
      <sell><volume>18831805139</volume><avg>6.32</avg><max>10.00</max><min>6.00</min><stddev>0.66</stddev><median>6.15</median><percentile>6.01</percentile></sell>
      <all><volume>38859293234</volume><avg>5.94</avg><max>10.00</max><min>0.50</min><stddev>0.85</stddev><median>5.91</median><percentile>4.26</percentile></all>
    </type></marketstat>
</evec_api>
```

Comment: Where is the code you are using that makes you think ET is not parsing the whole document? and which part of the XML is of interest? using `print ET.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)` will show you what it has.

Comment: I don't see any evidence given in this question that anything is missing/wrong at all. Requesting http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?usesystem=30000142&typeid=34, I get only the content you're showing in your output to be correctly parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need more details as to how you tried, but here is an example of iterating through the DOM tree:

```
In [339]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:x = """
:<evec_api version="2.0" method="marketstat_xml">
:  <marketstat><type id="34">
:      <buy><volume>14082197693</volume><avg>5.61</avg><max>5.89</max><min>4.61</min><stddev>0.46</stddev><median>5.57</median><percentile>5.87</percentile></buy>
:      <sell><volume>19614612791</volume><avg>6.31</avg><max>10.00</max><min>5.90</min><stddev>0.64</stddev><median>6.15</median><percentile>6.00</percentile></sell>
:      <all><volume>34096810484</volume><avg>5.95</avg><max>10.00</max><min>0.50</min><stddev>0.84</stddev><median>6.03</median><percentile>4.26</percentile></all>
:    </type></marketstat>
:</evec_api>"""
:<EOF>

In [340]: root = ET.fromstring(x)
In [342]: [(xx.text,xx.tag) for xx in root.iter()]
Out[342]: [('\n  ', 'evec_api'), (None, 'marketstat'), ('\n      ', 'type'), (None, 'buy'), ('14082197693', 'volume'), ('5.61', 'avg'), ('5.89', 'max'), ('4.61', 'min'), ('0.46', 'stddev'), ('5.57', 'median'), ('5.87', 'percentile'), (None, 'sell'), ('19614612791', 'volume'), ('6.31', 'avg'), ('10.00', 'max'), ('5.90', 'min'), ('0.64', 'stddev'), ('6.15', 'median'), ('6.00', 'percentile'), (None, 'all'), ('34096810484', 'volume'), ('5.95', 'avg'), ('10.00', 'max'), ('0.50', 'min'), ('0.84', 'stddev'), ('6.03', 'median'), ('4.26', 'percentile')]
```

Comment: Well, I tried several things to see if anything would work, and deleted and retryed plenty of code,  but basically I worked off this site: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html following the "Reading the data from a string:" approach.

Comment: @user2278224 do you get what you expect if you do a `print ET.tostring(root)` ?

Comment: I added what I get upon running `print ET.tostring(root)` I'm not sure exactly what I should expect from this bit of code, but this does seem to print the entire XML

Comment: @user2278224 What do you need from this XML document and how are you trying to get it?

Comment: I tried `print [(xx.tag,xx.text) for xx in root.iter()]` and it worked, everything was iterated correctly. So then I added parameters of 'avg', as this is the bit of info I need, and it narrowed to the 3 averages in the document. However I need to narrow it down to the <avg> just within the <buy> tag. Also, I don't quite understand what is going on, like for example why "xx" is being used and what purpose it serves. If I better understood that portion of the code, I might better understand how to use the code.

Answer (score 0):

@salparadise I have it working now and understand to a degree how it works. The code is:

```
root = ET.fromstring(data)
for buy in root.iter('buy'):
  av = buy.find('avg').text
avg = float(av)
print avg
```

Works like a charm. Thanks loads! The thing that is confusing about that tutorial I believe, is it assumes the root only has 1 child set as it were, so it gives the illusion everything can be parsed from the root's children, however in my XML, the root only has 1 direct child, which is fairly useless for data, that child, however, holds all the data in the sub-level below it. Thus the root.iter function.